# Is Google Analytics safe for websites that deal with sensitive information?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

I work for a company that writes several webapps that deal with a lot of sensitive information, such as full name, date of birth, address, and SSNs. Currently we don't have anything to measure site usage, but I would like to use Google Analytics to track usage and statistics about our users.

What data is sent to Google when you use Analytics? If I put this on a page that contains any of the above information, will that data be sent to Google? Or are they just getting the necessary information like user agent and IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'll get the IP, user agent and cookies from your users. If you're worried about using hosted analytics, you can look at hosting a program on your own servers to gather analytics such as [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/).

Comment: Wow! That looks a whole lot better than Piwik, I setup a Piwik website since I asked the question. Thanks for the info, I will definitively be checking out Open Web Analytics.

Comment: Yeah I like it better than Piwik, interface and features wise I think it's nicer